# Smart Quotes Elimination With Japanese Characters

Tags: php, mysql, string

Having smart quotes in a string was causing issues with storage in MYSQL and subsequent rendering. So I have a php function that replaces smart quotes with regular quotes.

However, when the string has Japanese characters, it converts some characters into a combination of non-printable character and a regular quote.

I am assuming that it is due to way the foreign language characters are encoded and there is a partial match with the smart-quote binary encoding causing this issue.

Here is a script that demonstrates the problem:

```
  <?php
  function convert_smart_quotes($string)
  {
      $search = array(chr(145),
      chr(146),
      chr(147),
      chr(148));

      $replace = array("'",
       "'",
       '"',
       '"');

      return str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
  }
 $input_str = "すっぴん美人になるためにやってはいけない「３スギ」とは？";
 $output_str = convert_smart_quotes($input_str);
 echo $output_str;
```

Basically, I want this function to work when it is latin characters based language string. At the same time, if it is a foreign language, I don't want it to mess up the string. Since there is no simple way to detect languages in php, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The smart quote and similar chars are  NOT valid values for the first byte of UTF-8 chars, BUT they can be VALID values for NON first bytes of UTF-8 chars.  So you need to try UTF-8 FIRST, then do the smart replace.  Please let me know if this helps and if you need more help.

```
UTF-8 Summary:
    0xxxxxxx
    110xxxxx10xxxxxx
    1110xxxx10xxxxxx10xxxxxx
    11110xxx10xxxxxx10xxxxxx10xxxxxx
    ...

--the x's are the UNICODE bits; smart quote is 10?????? which as shown above cannot be a first byte, but can be one of the other bytes)
```